# Building R package: "No man pages found in package"

Tags: r, package

My previously-functioning R package `lllcrc` recently broke, so I tweaked it, and now I'm having trouble building it again because it acts like it can't see my documentation files:

```
R CMD INSTALL lllcrc
* installing to library ‘/home/[...]/3.1’
* installing *source* package ‘lllcrc’ ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  ‘lllcrc’ 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (lllcrc)
```

This is totally weird because I definitely have a complete set of `.Rd` files in the `man` folder; in fact, I generated all of these using `roxygen2`, and all of this worked previously.  The R CMD INSTALL even works enough so that the package actually installs and all of its examples run.  But documentation is missing.  Running `?foo` just gives a "no documentation" message.

Another thing:  `R CMD Rd2pdf lllcrc` generates the .pdf documentation as I would expect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Still baffled, but I finally returned to an older working version, noticed that the problem does not appear there, and am re-doing my modifications.

Comment: How about `R CMD build lllcrc` first then `R CMD check lllcrc_*.tar.gz`?  I'd hope that would reveal more. You're not supposed to INSTALL directly from the directory like that. The `build` step cleans it, moves to `inst` and may give other messages.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same error message ... if you are using roxygen and RStudio then your problem might be the same. The reason became apparent when looking at "Configure build tools" in the "Build" drop-down menu: you need to tick the checkbox "Generate documentation with Roxygen". After that, everything worked.

Comment: I have the same issue but my build tools seem properly configured. Do you have any idea?